# This action could not be completed. Try again. While adding account in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add Apple developer account in Xcode Account Preferences and its giving below error.

**"This action could not be completed. Try again."**

I tried different Wi-Fi connections, Different Xcode Versions.

After removal of Apple Id, I am not able to add it again.

Your help could save my time as I am not able to Upload App on store.

[image]

Comment: After long search it helps but cleared My Mac Keychain.
**I had run following command on Terminal:**


sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared

Answer (score 1):

If you using

`sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
 sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared 
 sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared`

does not work. Update lastest itunes(for now 12.7.3)

Comment: You should update lastest itunes version @MaksimKniazev

Comment: I do not understand how iTunes has something do with this? Plus i can't install iTunes to beta 10.14 Mojave

Comment: I think xCode and iTunes using same functions or somethings like this. If your xcode version differences or incompatible with Itunes will be erros.

Comment: Installed iTunes, launched saying Unknown error occurred -04576 and it's crashing..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the device on iCloud. You can do it with your iPhone in the settings -> profile -> devices list -> macbook -> remove

or visit icloud.com and remove the device there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your iTunes is up to date. Out of the blue I couldn't sign in on my Mac into iCloud anymore, no matter wether it was System preferences, iTunes or Xcode. Changing permissions on `/Users/Shared` didn't help. I was about to give up and reinstall mac OS. Then I updated iTunes and - and voila, it worked again!