# Could not add GitHub account to Xcode; Clipped Error: GitHubHostBuiltInExtension.XCSo

Tags: xcode, github, devops

I am trying to connect my GitHub account with Xcode. When I put in my credentials an error occurs, displaying clipped text. The text is not selectable nor is the window resizable. Is there a way to view/inspect the window elements so I can see the full message? Or better yet is anyone familiar with the error?

***Note:*** Not sure if this is a question for here or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), I'll remove and repost on the other community if you guys think it's better suited.

Below is the partial error text and a screen shot.

> The operation couldn't be completed. (GitHubHostBuiltInExtension.XCSo...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [full error](https://github.com/keith/Xcode.app-strings/blob/master/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GitHubHostBuiltInExtension.appex/Contents/MacOS/GitHubHostBuiltInExtension#L161) should be:

```
GitHubHostBuiltInExtension.XCSourceControlHostRequestContext
```

It could be an [iCloud account issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47808472/6309), or a right issue on the  `/Users/Shared` folder.

```
 sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared 
 sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared  
 sudo chmod -R <userid>/Users/Shared
```